# The values passed through Insert into query doesn't display in rows. But a new row is added

Tags: php, mysql

When I send below query to the database from a php page, the passed values are not displaying. But each time a newrow is added.

```
$query1="INSERT INTO login(username,password,type)
VALUES("."'".$m_nic."',"."'".$f_name."',"."'".$type."')";
$login_set=mysql_query($query1,$connection);
```

Comment: The obvious question is, how/where are you setting `$m_nic`, `$f_name` and `$type`? If you're getting new, blank rows on each query that's probably the first place to look.

Comment: What type is your username, pw and type in your db? And what type are they in your php script?

Answer (score 0):

1. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. USe `mysqli_*`

Your code should look like this:

```
$q = mysqli_prepare($connection, 'INSERT INTO login (username, password, type) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'sss', $m_nic, $f_name, $type);
mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
```